# How to add Facebook show-faces="true" if I am not using <fb:login-button> tag?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented a custom FB login button and used Facebook javascript SDK, so I don't use

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

anymore. How can I implement show-faces functionality if I use FB.init (javascript SDK)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you get `show-faces` functionality unless you use Facebook's tools, otherwise it'd be a privacy violation. When you use XFBML to do that, you're getting back an iframe which is hosted by Facebook so you can't access those faces.

If you have a list of user IDs who have installed your application, you can simply get their picture via `https://graph.facebook.com/<ID>/picture?type=square`. Unlike the `fb:login` tag though, you won't be able to tell who the soon-to-be-installed user's friends are, so the faces you show them may not be relevant.

Comment: I am using FB oauth with FB javascript SDK, so I do not violate anything. I bet it's possible to implement that using FBL queries, but maybe there is a simpler solution

Comment: I misread your question - my apologies. I edited my answer, hopefully that helps.